# ^a$ no match found in test string aa?

Tags: regex

The test string "aa" starts with 'a', also ends with 'a', why still no match found?
How to understand the anchor "^" and "$" ?

Comment: Your regex allows only single `a`

Comment: Thanks, so how to understand anchors correctly?

Comment: Your anchors are correct, you need to quantify `a`. Try `^a+$` (one or more `a`)

Comment: See https://regex101.com/r/8mdAL4/2/debugger, and you will see how the engine tries to match `aa` with `^a$`. It is impossible to match  a 2-letter string with a pattern that can only match a 1 letter string.

Answer (score 1):

The "^" matches the beginning of an input e.g. /^A/ matches the A in "An animal". "$" matches the end of an input e.g. /t$/ matches t in "statement". Your regex, ^a$ failed because the same character doesn't exist both at the start AND at the end of your string.

Comment: Please see [markdown help](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help)

Answer (score 1):

`^` Asserts position at the start of the string.

`$` Asserts position at the end of the string.

To match 2 times `a`, this might be an option:

[`^a{2}$`](https://regex101.com/r/tOCyKM/2) or [`^aa$`](https://regex101.com/r/tOCyKM/1)

This page about [anchors](https://www.regular-expressions.info/anchors.html) might be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

+The "^" asserts the start of the string and "$" asserts the end.

You are saying, "match as string that starts, has one 'a' then ends.

If you want it to capture multiple 'a's too, then something like `/^a+$/ should do it.

Comment: I'd suggest changing `*` to `+` since `*` matches nothing, thus, an empty string would be matched by your regex. Also, please use [markdown](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help) in your answer

Comment: I would also suggest you use better terminology than `string that starts` since every string ever created `starts`. That seems a little broad to me.

Comment: Sorry ctwheels, I must have been making that edit while you were making that comment.